# Click on Slider based on the "Strong" tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I use Tampermonkey 4.5.5590 and Firefox Quantum.

I want to emphasize that I am a noob with these things and English is not my maternal language.

My code what it does is extract a number from the label "Strong" and select the Slider based on that number, the problem is that it does not select the Slider, however when adding a number in the label "li" without the variable, If you click on the Slider, how can I select the Slider based on the variable "selection"?

```
setInterval(function() {

$(function(){
var val = $("#messageBoxInline").text();

switch(val){
    default:
        var seleccion = document.querySelector(
        "strong.section-fourrage.section-fourrage-target"
        ).innerText;

        var div = document.getElementById('haySlider'),
        ol = div.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0],
        li = ol.getElementsByTagName('li')[seleccion].click();
        break;
}
});
}, 50);
```

Comment: `seleccion` is a string, which you need to convert to a numeric index, for example: `parseInt(seleccion)`

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, now it works, thanks :D